# Changing my account to username in opencart

Tags: opencart2.x

I have this small problem i am using open cart v 2.0.1.1 and when the user is logged in it shows my account with the drop down. I want to display the username of that particular user instead of " my account" can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the place to ask this as it isn't about programming.

Comment: where is the code that you have tried? or even how do you think it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

in case of you don't know how start
(1) you will need to read this post [How to become an open cart guru](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru)
(2) steps

- you will need to pass the name of the customer in some variable to the template file by adding it to `$data` array in `catalog/controller/common/header.php @ class ControllerCommonHeader @ function index`
- in the template file, change the part that checks whether the user is logged in or not, and add the passed customer name or the old header *My Account* depending on the branch